# router hash(#) symbol in vue 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using createWebHistory but it still stays in my hash url link `localhost/#/projects` Am I missing something while writing the code? How can i remove `#` symbol?

router

```
    const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    redirect: "/projects",
    component: () => import("@/layout-newLayout.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/projects",
        name: "projects",
        component: () => import("@/views/projects/index.vue"),
      },
    ],
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});
```

Comment: what history mode are you using in `createRouter`? i.e. are you using Hash Mode or HTML5 Mode for your vue-router?

Comment: @JaromandaX ı used it but I get an error when I type Array<RouteRecordRaw> in

Comment: you used it? you used WHAT?

Comment: @JaromandaX createRouter ofc

Comment: huh? you never mentioned that error - so, you haven't used `createRouter` at all??? aren't routes in createRouter typed `Readonly<RouteRecordRaw[]>`

Comment: ok, so you're using `createWebHashHistory` so that's why the `#` - as for anything else - you didn't ask in the question

Comment: Updated question. Could you check question

Comment: that update makes naff all difference - the `#` is because you use `createWebHashHistory` ... you never mentioned an error in the question, so there is no error to speak of

Comment: @SpongeCoder Use `createWebHistory()` instead of `createWebHashHistory()`. Read the docs... https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode

Comment: @Marc - using WebHistory requires more than basic knowledge of http server configuration 

Comment: @Marc I tried it but as i said I got an error `Array<RouteRecordRaw>`

Comment: @JaromandaX But that's literally what he is asking for, or did i over read something?

Comment: @SpongeCoder Are you using SSR or is your code running in node.js and not the browser? Add some more details and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `I get an error` - do we guess, or will you share the error with us so we can help you

Comment: Is there a mistake in my code spelling? the question is just that

Comment: `I get an error` - what is the exact wording of the error

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated the question, can you take a look again?

Comment: so, you've fixed the error now? perhaps your browser needs to be restarted - if it's chrome, you definitely do

Comment: @JaromandaX I revised the code again like this. I don't get any errors, but the `#` symbol stays in place, even though i restarted the project

Answer (score 0):

The use of the 'hash' comes from the history mode you are using. You can change the mode to several others, but note for some you will need to add some server-side support if you wish to allow the URL to link back into the application.

Full details and code samples in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html).

Comment: ı used it but I get an error when I type Array<RouteRecordRaw> in

Comment: @SpongeCoder Mentioning that you get an error isn't very useful. At least share some more info. What does the error say?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I updated the question, can you take a look again?

Comment: @SpongeCoder Please provide a minimal example with no extraneous variables, and try it before posting. The docs linked above have several working examples.